# Auto Count Up System

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website and on the home page I need the count to go from 1 up to ~. I have looked around at different websites but none of them can give me the answer.

I am looking around for this code to be added with the website.

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Website Name</h1>
   <p>Website Description</p>
   <p><a href="#">
     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a>
   </a></p>
  </div>
  <footer class="text-center">
   <p>
       XXX Servers Registered | XXX Servers Reviewed
   </p>
  </footer>
 </div>
```

This website needs the 'XXX' to count up, a example of what I am looking for is located here http://minecraft.net/ they have a good example of what I am looking for and what I am aiming to get out of this.

There is one problem with the counting up system thats on Minecrafts website, that I think it goes a bit fast, I need this looking real and that it looks like people are actally registering and not a piece of code thats counting up in 1000's.

I really hope that you would be able to help because I am really at this moment needing help.

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this plugin, it seems highly configurable in terms of speed.

[countUp.js](http://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/)

Comment: That looks good but I would need something to keep ticking and not reach a target then stop.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store the data somewhere in a database. Make it count up by 1 once someone registered. Then get the data out of the database at the page and you could make that refresh on the page every ~10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to have an aditional table in database, where you increment the number when someone registers a server, or someone reviews one. you could try something like this for the query:

```
INSERT INTO servers VALUES (x1,x2,x3);
```

and then, before going further:

```
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (numbers+1);
```

and then use ajax to retreive the data from numbers dynamically!